# Drawing Bounding box around given size Area contour

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I want to draw a bounding box around each closed contour of an area larger than some threshold, not just the biggest contour. How can I go about doing this?
So far this is what I have tried:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if rect[2] < 100 or rect[3] < 100: continue
    print cv2.contourArea(c)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.putText(im,'Moth Detected',(x+w+10,y+h),0,0.3,(0,255,0))
cv2.imshow("Show",im)
cv2.waitKey()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried to fix your code formatting, but feel free to edit again if the meaning of the code has changed, since whitespace matters in Python.

Comment: Could you also describe what the problem is that you're experiencing? What is the current behavior compared to what you expect? I just tried your code (post-edit), and it draws contours around more than one contour.

Comment: Hi Aurelius , Thanks for Editing , it actually works now , Indenting was the problem ., if you would like the votes up, rewrite as answer and ill vote it up.Thanks

Comment: I've rolled back my last edit, since it fundamentally changed the nature of your code. See my answer for a working version.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Remember, your indentation level matters in Python. It's also worth noting that your code doesn't necessarily draw a box around the largest contour, it draws a box around the last element of `contours`. Fortunately, the fix is simple. You just need to indent your calls to `cv2.rectangle()` and `cv2.putText()` so they evaluate on every loop iteration. You can also eliminate a call to `cv2.boundingRect()` by expanding `rect` into `x,y,w,h`. Your code would then be:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if rect[2] < 100 or rect[3] < 100: continue
    print cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = rect
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.putText(im,'Moth Detected',(x+w+10,y+h),0,0.3,(0,255,0))
cv2.imshow("Show",im)
cv2.waitKey()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```